# How can I prove this implication?

Tags: real-analysis

Which double integral properties lead to the conclusion that if the double integral of the function is equal to $0$, the integrand expression is equal to zero?

$$\iint_D\Delta u \ \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d}y = 0\implies \Delta u = 0$$

Comment: Well, it's certainly true if $\Delta u\geq0$ on $D$...

Comment: And it's >=0, but i don't know why is it true

Comment: I suppose $\Delta u$ is continuous as well.

Comment: @Justyna Any nonegative continuous function has a non-negative integral, and if the function is greater than $0$ in at least one point, then it is greater than $0$ in a ball, and so its integral must be greater than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt a proof by contrapositive. Assume $f$ is a continuous, nonnegative function that is not always $0$ on its domain $[a,b]$. Then there exists an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$. Let $\varepsilon=\frac{f(x_0)}2$. Because $f$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. In other words, $f(x)\in\left(f(x_0)-\frac{f(x_0)}2,f(x_0)+\frac{f(x_0)}2\right)$. Therefore,

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\ge\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f(x)dx\ge\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\frac{f(x_0)}2dx=f(x_0)\delta>0$$

And so the integral of $f$ over its domain must be greater than $0$. $~~~~{\square}$

So now we have that $\int f=0\Rightarrow f=0$. Then, $\iint f(x,y)dxdy = 0\Rightarrow\forall y(\int f(x,y)dx=0)$. Furthermore, $\int f(x,y)dx=0\Rightarrow\forall x(f(x,y)=0)$. So finally, $f(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: There are some details to be ironed out here, but I hope the general idea is clear.